# Add data programmatically to an umbraco node

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I need to add some value to my umbraco node.
I had tried something like this

```
Node node = Node.GetCurrent();
node.GetProperty("pass_word").Value = password.ToString()
```

But it throws error that it is read only.Can any one give any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Umbraco caches the nodes' properties in an xml file, called umbraco.config. When you use NodeFactory to access a node's properties, it is pulling from the cache, and therefore read only.

To actually edit the data found in the database and then in turn have it published to the cache you will need to use the Document class. See [Difference between Node and Document](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/difference-between-node-and-document) for more details.

Here's an example:

```
int id = Node.GetCurrent().Id;
Document node = new Document(id);
node.getProperty("pass_word").Value = password.ToString();
node.Publish(new User(0));
umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Umbraco there is a difference between a Node and a Document. A node is read from the XML file umbraco.config through the nodeFactory and is used for retrieving and displaying data from your content the fastest way.

Modifying a Node is not possible and makes no sense as the XML in the Umbraco.config file is generated after each publish from the Document data inside the database.

If you need to modify the data in your database, you must work with Document types.
See [this article](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/difference-between-node-and-document) about the difference between a Node and a Document

Comment: Ha ha! We must have answered the question at the exact same time!

Comment: Yes we did, after I posted mine, I suddenly saw your answer as well ;)